# An inequality improvement on AMM 11145

Tags: inequalities

I have asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853354/stronger-version-of-amm-problem-11145-april-2005) in math.stackexchange, I am reposting it here, looking for answers:

How to show that for $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n >0$ real numbers and for $n \ge 3$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{k}}\le\left(2-\dfrac{7\ln{2}}{8\ln{n}}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_{k}}$$

Comment: Why are you sure that this is true?

Comment: @FedorPetrov robjohn verified the inequality for $n = 2$ case (mentioned in [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853354/stronger-version-of-amm-problem-11145-april-2005#comment1760860_853354) ), but I don't have a access to a mathematical software that might check the validity of the result in general.

Comment: there is a solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291441/an-inequality-between-series) with constant equal to 2. your constant is sharper .

Comment: @S.Zoalroshd thanks! I am aware of the proof for the constant being $2$ (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/846240/129017) ) but I couldn't prove this improved inequality claiming it can be replaced by: $2 - \frac{7\ln 2}{8\ln n}$

Comment: @r9m: each of our proofs shows that we can get $2\left(1-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)$, but this is not as good as $2\left(1-\dfrac{7\ln{2}}{16\ln{n}}\right)$.

Comment: $\frac78\ln2$ is an unusual (and remarkably precise, for want of a better word) value for the constant here - can you speak to its specific genesis?

Comment: The constant is claimed here: http://www.math.org.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=28918  (The Chinese above the inequality simply says, "We have the stronger [inequality]".)  Although that was 2 years ago, perhaps someone could try posting a followup asking for a proof.

Comment: The right side is independent of the order of the $a_i$s but the left side is not.  So which order makes the left side largest?

Comment: @TimothyChow It could interesting to find out if the OP had a particular sequence in mind that hit that particular constant. The transIation sounds like "stronger inequality" not necessarily "the best inequality".

Comment: I think the constant is a red herring -- I feel the "true" bound should be of the form $2\left(1 - \frac{n}{(n+1)\log n}\right)$....

Comment: @Suvrit the constant $\frac{7\ln 2}{16}$ doesn't matter, what is important is how the $\frac{1}{\log n}$ comes into play. Do you have a proof (or even a heuristics) that supports the claim? thanks!

Comment: @r9m The intuition for $\frac{c}{\ln n}$ could come from the case where $a(k)\,=\,k$. In that case $C(n)=2 (1 - \frac{n} {(n+1) H_n})$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ harmonic number, and it's known that $H_n$ is $\mathcal{O}(\ln n)$. Of course, to move from heuristics to proof, one would have to actually show that $a(k)=k$ is the "*worst case*" sequence i.e. that it maximizes the ratio of the LHS vs RHS.

Comment: @Timothy Chow A earlier source: In 2013/09/19, someone asked for proof of the inequality with constant 2 in a Chinese forum and one hour later, Ji Chen gave a proof and proposed the inequality with constant $2-\dfrac{7\ln{2}}{8\ln{n}}$.

Answer (score 5):

(extended comment)

Choose some positive numbers $b_1,\dots,b_n$ and denote $a_i=ic_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Use Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_ic_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_ic_i^{-1}\right)\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\right)^2$$ to estimate
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{\sum_{i=1}^k b_ic_i}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{k b_i c_i^{-1}}{(b_1+\dots+b_k)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^{-1}b_i\sum_{k=i}^n\frac{k}{(b_1+\dots+b_k)^2}.
$$
Thus if some positive number $\alpha$ satisfies 
$$
b_i^2\sum_{k=i}^n\frac{k}{(b_1+\dots+b_k)^2}\leq \alpha,i=1,\dots,n,
$$
then we get desired inequality 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i}\leq \alpha \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{a_i}.
$$
Choice of $b_i=i$ gives $\alpha=2$ or bit better, but there are rooms for improvement, since for large values $i$ (close to $n$) inequality becomes not very much sharp.

Say, we may try $b_k=k+\lambda$ and optimize by $\lambda$.

Answer (score 5):

An extended comment that has a chance of being useful.

First, note that if you interchange $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ then only the $k$-th term on the left side changes and the right side doesn't change at all.  From this we can easily see that the worst order for a given set of values is $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots \le a_n$.

Now consider adjusting both $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ so that the right side remains unchanged. If $a_k\mapsto a_k+\epsilon$ then $a_{k+1}\mapsto a_{k+1} - \epsilon(a_{k+1}/a_{k})^2+O(\epsilon^2)$.  If we are sitting at the worst left side for given right side, then the effect of this adjustment must be $O(\epsilon^2)$ for all $k$.  I think that this will give the worst sequence exactly by working from the last term backwards, but I'm out of time just now.

An extension of this approach is to consider adjusting three consecutive terms so that their sum and reciprocal sum both remain the same. Then only two terms of the left side will change so the total effect on the left side can be determined to obtain an explicit condition satisfied by the worst sequence.

I'll start on the last suggestion. First note that for $a,b,c\ge 0$, if we tweak them like this:
$$ a\mapsto a+\epsilon, \quad
   b\mapsto b-\frac{b^2(c^2-a^2)}{a^2(c^2-b^2)}\epsilon, \quad
   c\mapsto c+\frac{c^2(b^2-a^2)}{a^2(c^2-b^2)}\epsilon $$
then both $x+y+z$ and $1/x+1/y+1/z$ change by only $O(\epsilon^2)$.
So now tweak $a_{k-2},a_{k-1},a_k$ like that.  Up to $O(\epsilon^2)$,
the right side doesn't change and the left side changes by $\Delta_k\epsilon$,
where
$$ \Delta_k = -\frac{k-2}{S_{k-2}^2} + \frac{k-1}{S_{k-1}^2}\,
   \frac{a_k^2(a_{k-1}^2-a_{k-2}^2))}{a_{k-2}^2(a_k^2-a_{k-1}^2))}, $$
writing $S_t=\sum_{i=1}^t a_i$.  If we are looking at the largest possible
left side for given right side, then we must have $\Delta_k=0$ for $3\le k\le n$.
This determines $a_3,\ldots,a_n$ in terms of $a_1,a_2$.  We can also
take $a_1=1$ wlog, so there is one free parameter $a_2$.

Note that for given $a_2$ the sequence is independent of $n$, however for any $a_2>1$, the sequence becomes complex for large enough $n$. The best value of $a_2$ depends on $n$.

Here are numerical values for the maximum value of the left side divided by $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/a_k$, and the approximate value $\hat a_2$ of $a_2$ that achieves it. Also the claimed bound $2-(7 \ln 2)/(8\ln n)$.

n=2, max=1.125, $\hat a_2$=3.000, bnd=1.125
  n=3, max=1.205, $\hat a_2$=2.426, bnd=1.448
  n=4, max=1.261, $\hat a_2$=2.20, bnd=1.563
  n=5, max=1.303, $\hat a_2$=2.07, bnd=1.623
  n=10, max=1.425 $\hat a_2$=1.83, bnd=1.737
  n=100, max=1.6844 $\hat a_2$=1.5688, bnd=1.868

These values suggest that the claimed bound is correct, but far from sharp except for $n=2$.

Here is the optimal sequence for $n=100$: 1.0, 1.56881, 2.10179, 2.62862, 3.15987, 3.70074, 4.25434, 4.82275, 5.40752, 6.00993, 6.63103, 7.27180, 7.93314, 8.61591, 9.32096, 10.0491, 10.8013, 11.5783, 12.3810, 13.2103, 14.0673, 14.9527, 15.8678, 16.8135, 17.7909, 18.8012, 19.8456, 20.9254, 22.0419, 23.1965, 24.3906, 25.6258, 26.9037, 28.2261, 29.5947, 31.0114, 32.4783, 33.9974, 35.5710, 37.2016, 38.8915, 40.6436, 42.4605, 44.3455, 46.3016, 48.3323, 50.4413, 52.6325, 54.9100, 57.2782, 59.7421, 62.3066, 64.9774, 67.7603, 70.6618, 73.6887, 76.8485, 80.1493, 83.5998, 87.2096, 90.9890, 94.9493, 99.1028, 103.463, 108.045, 112.865, 117.942, 123.294, 128.945, 134.919, 141.244, 147.950, 155.074, 162.653, 170.734, 179.367, 188.610, 198.531, 209.209, 220.733, 233.213, 246.773, 261.566, 277.773, 295.617, 315.370, 337.372, 362.055, 389.972, 421.852, 458.671, 501.779, 553.098, 615.480, 693.382, 794.237, 931.624, 1133.84, 1473.84, 2238.74

Comment: That's a good observation. The premise was noted "en passant" by @1015 in the same post linked from my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999/the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-n-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-dotsb-fra/600943#600943 (see `remark`) but it was not followed up on.

Comment: I think the "correct" bound will be roughly of the form $2(1 - \frac{n}{(n+1)\log n})$, which seems more natural also.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers. Defining $C(n)$ as the tightest bound for $n$ then $C(1)=1$ (trivially), $C(2)=\frac{9}{8}$ (easily), and $C(3)=1.20469..$ (1.205 in your table) looks to be the smaller positive real root of $9 C^4-72 C^3+376 C^2-1440 C+1296$. Sort of dampens the hope for a "nice" $C(n)$ at this point, except maybe asymptotically.

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, I agree with that polynomial to over 20 digits. It's clear that all the values will be algebraic numbers, but the degree probably explodes.

Comment: @ dxiv: And $\hat a_2$=2.425977.. is a root of $13A^4-20A^3-44A^2+24A+36$, proved rigorously.

Answer (score 4):

(*This doesn't answer the actual question, but it was too long for a comment.Besides, it's related, and someone might even find it relevant.*)

The following attempts $(1)$ to prove a non-discrete counterpart using integrals to the AMM 11145 inequality for an arbitrary real function $a(x)$ that is integrable and strictly positive on $[0, n]$:
$$
\int_0^n \frac{k}{\int_0^k a(x)\,dx}\,dk\leq 2\int_0^n \frac{1}{a(k)}\,dk
$$
and also $(2)$ prove that $2$ is the smallest constant for which it holds.

The notations are to emphasize the relationship to the discrete case, but $n, k, x, a(x)$ are all reals, of course. An equivalent integral inequality for $[0,\infty)$ was mentioned by @1015 here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999/the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-n-frac1a-1-frac1a-2-dotsb-fra/600943#600943 but was not elaborated or further pursued at the time.

$(1)$ The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for real-valued functions

$$
\left\lvert{\int_0^k f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}\right\rvert^2 \le \int_0^k f(x)^2 \,dx \int_0^k g(x)^2 \,dx 
$$
written for $f(x) = x / {\sqrt{(a(x))}}$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{(a(x))}$ gives

$$
\left\lvert{\int_0^k{x\,dx}}\right\rvert^2 \le \int_0^k \frac{x^2}{a(x)}\,dx\;\int_0^k a(x)\,dx
$$

then replacing the left hand side with the obvious $k^4 / 4$ and rearranging

$$
\frac{k}{\int_0^k a(x)\,dx} \le \frac{4}{k^3}\;\int_0^k\frac{x^2}{a(x)}\,dx
$$

Integrating in $k$ over $[0, n]$ then applying Fubini's theorem and simplifying gives

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^n \frac {k} {\int_0^k a(x)\,dx}\,dk & \le \int_0^n \int_0^k\frac{4}{k^3}\; \frac{x^2}{a(x)}\,dk\,dx \\
& = \int_0^n \int_x^n\frac{4\,x^2}{a(x)}\; \frac{1}{k^3}\,dx\,dk \\
& = \int_0^n \frac{4\,x^2}{a(x)}\; (\frac{1}{2\,x^2} - \frac{1}{2\,n^2})\,dx \\
& = 2\;\int_0^n \frac{1}{a(x)}\; (1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2})\,dx \\
& \le 2\;\int_0^n \frac{1}{a(x)}\,dx = 2\;\int_0^n \frac{1}{a(k)}\,dk
\end{align}
$$

which proves the claimed inequality.

$(2)$ To prove that $C = 2$ is the *best* constant, consider the function $a(x) = x + \epsilon$. After calculating the elementary integrals, the inequality reduces to:

$$
2\,(\,ln(n + 2\,\epsilon) - ln(2\,\epsilon)\,) \le 2\,(\,ln(n + \epsilon) - ln(\epsilon))
$$

The ratio of the two sides approaches $1$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ as can be easily verified using l'Hopital rule for example:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}{ln(n + 2\,\epsilon) - ln(2\,\epsilon) \over ln(n + \epsilon) - ln(\epsilon)} = {\frac{2}{n+2\,\epsilon} - \frac{2}{2\,\epsilon} \over \frac{1}{n+\epsilon} - \frac{1}{\epsilon}} = {\frac{-\,n}{n + 2\,\epsilon} \over \frac{-\,n}{n+\epsilon}} = 1
\end{align}
$$

...which indicates that any constant $C' < 2$ would fail to satisfy the inequality for small enough $\epsilon$.

To sum it up, the result itself is not surprising. The proofs for the discrete case inequality usually showed that $2$ is the best constant for arbitrarily large series as well. The formulation using integrals just allows for the equivalent of such infinite series to occur within a finite $[0,n]$ interval. It might be also worth noting that the linear function used in the second step reminisces of the proofs by harmonic numbers in the discrete case (that $2$ is optimal for infinite series).

Comment: You seem to be avoiding the main issue by letting the integrals start at zero (instead of $1$, say). If you hadn't done that, then the best constant will be strictly less than $2$, and I don't think there's any essential difference between the continuous and discrete settings then.

Comment: @ChristianRemling `a(x)` is assumed to be `strictly positive on [0,n]` as stated. I don't see how the lower bound, 0 or otherwise, changes anything. Please feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Your proof shows that $2(1-1/n^2)$ works if the integrals start at $1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I don't see how that would follow. If you have a proof please post it and I'll be happy to ammend or retract mine.

Comment: It's obvious, given what you already did, just estimate $1-x^2/n^2\le 1-1/n^2$ in your last step in (1). But of course this is a far cry from $1-c/\log n$, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @ChristianRemling That only holds for $x \ge 1$ which is not guaranteed here. And if you shifted the $[0,n]$ to something else like an arbitrary $[a,b]$ interval, then the proposed inequality would still hold, but that particular factor would no longer be $(1 - x^2 / n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something years ago which is similar to Fedor Petrov's (or other users').

Problem: Let $a_i > 0; \ i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ ($n\ge 2$). Let $C(n) = 2 - \frac{7\ln 2}{8\ln n}$. Prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k}
\le C(n)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}.$$

Introducing the coefficients (to be determined) $C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_n > 0$, by the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{k}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k} \le \frac{k}{(C_1+C_2 + \cdots + C_n)^2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{C_i^2}{a_i}$$
and
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k} 
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{(C_1+C_2 + \cdots + C_n)^2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{C_i^2}{a_i}\\
&=  \sum_{k=1}^n \Big[C_k^2\sum_{m=k}^n \frac{m}{(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_m)^2}\Big]\frac{1}{a_k}.
\end{align}
Equality occurs if and only if $C_k = a_k, \ k=1, 2, \cdots, n$.

The problem becomes: Can we choose $C_k > 0,\ k=1, 2, \cdots, n$ such that 
$$\sup_{k=1, 2, \cdots, n} C_k^2\sum_{m=k}^n \frac{m}{(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_m)^2} \le C(n), \ \forall n\ge 2 ?$$

It is easy if $C(n)=2$. For a simple proof, I chose $$C_k = \sqrt{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)} - \sqrt{(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2)}, \ k = 1, 2, \cdots, n.$$
We have $C_1 + C_2 + \cdots + C_m = \sqrt{m(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)}$ and
\begin{align}
&C_k^2\sum_{m=k}^n \frac{m}{(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_m)^2}\\
= \ &k(k+1)(k+2)\big(2k+2 - 2\sqrt{(k+3)(k-1)}\big)\\
&\quad \cdot\Big(\frac{1}{2(k+1)} - \frac{1}{2(k+2)} - \frac{1}{2(n+2)(n+3)}\Big)\\
\le \ & k(k+1)(k+2)\big(2k+2 - 2\sqrt{(k+3)(k-1)}\big)
\Big(\frac{1}{2(k+1)} - \frac{1}{2(k+2)}\Big)\\
\le \ & 2.
\end{align}

Fedor Petrov chose $C_k = k,\ \forall k$. We have
$$C_k^2\sum_{m=k}^n \frac{m}{(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_m)^2} = 
k^2\Big(-\frac{4}{n+1}+4\Psi(1, n+2)+\frac{4}{k}-4\Psi(1, 1+k)\Big).$$
Denote the RHS as $f(k, n)$. 
We have the asymptotic expansion $f(\sqrt{n}, n) \sim 2 - \frac{2}{3\sqrt{n}} - \frac{2}{n} + \cdots (n\to \infty)$.
Thus, it at most gives $C(n) \ge 2 - \frac{A}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $A$ is a constant.

Fedor Petrov also suggested $C_k = k + \lambda$ (optimize $\lambda$). If $\lambda$ is a constant, similarly,
we have $f(\sqrt{n},n, \lambda) \sim 2 - \frac{4\lambda + 2}{3\sqrt{n}} - \cdots (n \to \infty)$.
It is not enough.

Comment: (+1) I tried something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/846240/129017) earlier and couldn't improve it to anything nearing the $\frac{c}{\ln n}$ decay claimed in the inequality.

Comment: Yes. As dxiv commented, in the original inequality, when $a_k = k, \forall k$, it results in $C(n) \sim 2 - \frac{A}{\ln n}$. However, in our setting, $C_k = k, \forall k$ is not enough.